# Unterschied zwischen sorgen, kümmern, (sich) beschäftigen, betreuen

Tags: verb, vocabulary

Welchen Unterschied gibt es zwischen:

- sorgen für,
- sich kümmern um,
- betreuen,
- sich beschäftigen mit?

Answer (score 2):

Die Wörter sind von der Bedeutung relativ ähnlich mit der Ausnahme von "sich beschäftigen mit".

**Beispiel**: "In meiner Firma beschäftige ich mich mit Qualitätssicherung" gegenüber: "In meiner Firma kümmere ich mich um die Qualitätssicherung". Im ersten Satz ist das möglicherweise so, dass diese Aufgabe nur eine von vielen ist und vermutlich auch nicht die wichtigste. Den zweiten Satz würde jemand sagen, dessen Hauptaufgabe die Qualitätssicherung ist, vielleicht sogar als Verantwortlicher.

Bei den sonstigen Worten gibt es wie immer Unterschiede in welchem Kontext sie verwendet werden:

- *betreuen* wird verwendet mit Personen oder einem Projekt: "ich betreue halbtags meine Kinder, und im Beruf betreue ich die Entwicklung unserer Batteriesysteme als Projektleiter."
- *sorgen für* etwas geht in die Richtung: eine Resource, Information oder ähnliches bereitstellen: "bei der Hochzeitsfeier sorge ich für Tischdekoration und für den reibungslosen Ablauf der Kinderbetreuung"
- *sich sorgen um* bezieht sich wieder auf ein Ziel (Person, Projekt, Erfolg) aber in dem Fall, wenn es nicht so gut läuft: "Alexander sah gestern gar nicht gut aus, ich sorge mich um seine Gesundheit" oder: "Wir sind bei der Entwicklung von X stark hintendran, ich sorge mich um den Produktionsanlauf der ja Ende des Jahres geplant ist" (wobei: in beiden Fällen würde ich eher sagen: "ich mache mir Sorgen um X")
- *sich kümmern um* kann sowohl wie "betreuen" als auch wie "sorgen für verwenden"

Comment: "In meiner Firma kümmere ich mich um die Qualitätssicherung" würde ich umgekehrt interpretieren. Das würde eher jemand sagen, der als einziger oder Hauptverantwortlicher für die Qualitätssicherung zuständig ist. Aber auch das muß eigentlich nicht sein, es können sich durchaus mehrere Leute um mehrere Bereiche kümmern.

Comment: "Ich sorge für meine Eltern" meint nicht (normalerweise) das ich meine Eltern als Ressource bereitstelle, wohl aber das ich meinen Eltern Ressourcen zur Verfügung stelle.